# Oracle 10g Enterprise manager charts issue

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle-enterprise-manager

Heloo,
Database is Oracle Database 10g Release 10.2.0.5.0 - 64bit Production.
RAC with 2 nodes.
In EM on activity i have situations like below:

[image: Node1]

[image: Node2]

Why are gaps in chart with active sessions.
In this period of time, on each node where at least 4 active session.

Thank you.

Comment: You would need to dig further. I would look into the raw ASH data for that time period.

Comment: What is ASH? Where to look exactly ?

Comment: ASH is Active Session History. Depending on the activity, you may find the data sill in v$active_session_history. Otherwise, you will need to go to DBA_HIST_ACTIVE_SESS_HISTORY, but here the data is stored at a lower granularity, 10s vs 1s. At the end of the day, it might just be (lack of) instrumentation, but you can at least interrogate the data and see if there is anything interesting. Finally, it's very important to understand "ASH Math". The data is sampled, so certain types of math do not make sense.

Comment: Here is a good resource, from some of the actual ASH architects: https://www.slideshare.net/jberesni/ash-architecture-and-advanced-usage-rmoug2014-36611678